# glfw and glew not rendering (glDrawElements with VAO)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'll dump all the information. I am using c++. No matter what I try, `glClear()` works and rendering a mesh doesn't. There are no errors.

I have switched from freeglut to glfw. I had no problems before. I have the glfw3 dll and lib and the same for glew. I also have the OpenGL32 lib linked because of unresolved externals.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the libraries are up to date with the latest.

I got glfw from main glfw site and downloaded the 64 bit binaries. I got glew 32 and 64 bit binaries from [http://glew.sourceforge.net/](https://glew.sourceforge.net/). I compile as 64 bit and run it on windows 10 64 bit.

It currently compiles and runs without code errors.

EDIT:
I have taken some advice but still see no quad. Thanks for the input.

The new code:

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

GLFWwindow * window;
int width;
int height;

unsigned int vertex_array_buffer;
unsigned int vertex_buffer;
unsigned int index_buffer;

float vertex_model[24] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

unsigned int index_model[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3
};

unsigned int program;

float ratio;

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "RenderEngine v0.0.0", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit()) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    unsigned int vert_shader;
    unsigned int frag_shader;

    const char * vert_shader_text;
    const char * frag_shader_text;

    std::ifstream file;
    std::string buffer;
    size_t f_size;

    file.open("shader.vert", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    f_size = file.tellg();
    buffer.resize(f_size);
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(&buffer[0], f_size);
    file.close();

    vert_shader_text = buffer.c_str();

    buffer.clear();

    file.open("shader.frag", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    f_size = file.tellg();
    buffer.resize(f_size);
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(&buffer[0], f_size);
    file.close();

    frag_shader_text = buffer.c_str();

    vert_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vert_shader, 1, &vert_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vert_shader);

    int result = GL_FALSE;
    int log_length;

    glGetShaderiv(vert_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    glGetShaderiv(vert_shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
    std::vector<char> vert_shader_error((log_length > 1) ? log_length : 1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vert_shader, log_length, NULL, &vert_shader_error[0]);
    std::cout << &vert_shader_error[0] << '\n';

    result = GL_FALSE;

    frag_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(frag_shader, 1, &frag_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(frag_shader);

    glGetShaderiv(frag_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    glGetShaderiv(frag_shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
    std::vector<char> frag_shader_error((log_length > 1) ? log_length : 1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(frag_shader, log_length, NULL, &frag_shader_error[0]);
    std::cout << &frag_shader_error[0] << '\n';

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vert_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, frag_shader);

    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "pos");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "color");

    glLinkProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vert_shader);
    glDeleteShader(frag_shader);

    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
    std::vector<char> program_error((log_length > 1) ? log_length : 1);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, log_length, NULL, &program_error[0]);
    std::cout << &program_error[0] << '\n';

    glUseProgram(program);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_buffer);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_buffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_model), vertex_model, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
    glGenBuffers(1, &index_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index_model), index_model, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    if (glGetError()) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_buffer);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Also the shader files if you need them. The vertex shader:

```cpp
#version 330

in layout(location = 0) vec3 pos;
in layout(location = 1) vec3 color;

out vec3 out_color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0f);
    out_color = color;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```cpp
#version 330

in vec3 out_color;

out vec4 final_color;

void main() {
    final_color = vec4(out_color, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error checking in your code (like `glGetError`, `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`, `GL_LINK_STATUS`, ...) so how do you know that there are no errors? I can't verify it right now but imho `GL_QUADS` is not a valid `mode` for `glDrawElements` or was at least removed at around `3.2`

Comment: I have changed to GL_TRIANGLES but haven't had good luck.

Comment: I don't see that you added any error checking to determine where the error occurs.

Comment: I have now but its already answered bellow.

Comment: @JoeCool: If you want to show the answer you used, you post an answer. You don't put the answer in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- Even *Intel* supports OpenGL 3.3 Core contexts nowadays.  Request one:

  ```
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  ```
- Verify your shaders actually compile/link.  On my system the vertex shader failed with:

  ```
  Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
  ERROR: 0:3: error(#12) Unexpected qualifier
  ERROR: 0:4: error(#12) Unexpected qualifier
  ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors.  No code generated
  ```

  `layout()` should be placed before `in`:

  ```
  layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
  layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;
  ```
- Unbind your `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` *after* you unbind the VAO.
- `index_model` is indexing right off the end of `vertex_model`.  Don't do that unless you like access violations way down in the innards of your OpenGL driver :)

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

All together:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader( obj ) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram( obj ) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader( obj ) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram( obj ) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

const char* vert = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec3 out_color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0f);
    out_color = color;
}
)GLSL";

const char* frag = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core

in vec3 out_color;

out vec4 final_color;

void main() {
    final_color = vec4(out_color, 1.0f);
}
)GLSL";

GLFWwindow * window;
int width;
int height;

unsigned int vertex_array_buffer;
unsigned int vertex_buffer;
unsigned int index_buffer;

float vertex_model[] =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

unsigned int index_model[] =
{
    0, 1, 2,
};

unsigned int program;

float ratio;

int main()
{
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        exit( -1 );
    }

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "RenderEngine v0.0.0", NULL, NULL );
    if( !window )
    {
        exit( -1 );
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    if( glewInit() )
    {
        exit( -1 );
    }

    glfwSwapInterval( 1 );

    GLuint program = Program::Load( vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL );
    glUseProgram( program );

    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vertex_array_buffer );
    glBindVertexArray( vertex_array_buffer );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &vertex_buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertex_model ), vertex_model, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( float ) * 6, (void*)0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( float ) * 6, (void*)( sizeof( float ) * 3 ) );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &index_buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( index_model ), index_model, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &width, &height );
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glBindVertexArray( vertex_array_buffer );
        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr );
        glBindVertexArray( 0 );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow( window );
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try to edit it work like the original program. :)

Answer (score 1):

`glVertexAttribPointer` takes passed arguments and **currently bound VBO** and saves that information inside the state of **currently** bound VAO.

`glEnableVertexAttribArray` enables an attribute also just in **currently** bound VAO. You enable them too early.

So, the correct order of doing things is:

1. Bind VAO
2. Bind VBO
3. Call `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`
4. Now you can unbind the VBO or repeat 2-3 because 3. saved the state into VAO.
5. Unbind VAO

Index buffer should be placed anywhere between 1-5. Just take care to not accidentally unbind the index buffer too early - while VAO is still bound. Because VAO only remembers one index buffer.

Other than those early calls, I did not find any more mistakes.

This "hidden" capture of VBO has been "revealed" in OpenGL 4.5 by splitting the functionality of `glVertexAttribPointer` into `glVertexArrayAttribBinding`, `glVertexArrayAttribFormat` and `glBindVertexBuffer`.

Comment: I took your advice but I have not seen anything different but a black window. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The named [index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) object is a state of the [vertex array object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)s state vector.
If you do `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)`, when the vertex array object is bound, then the reference to the element buffer is broken.

Delete `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`, to solve the issue:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_buffer);
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_buffer);

// [...]

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);

// [...]

//glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // <---- skip this
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

---

In the array of vertices there are 4 coordinates and color attributes, so the indices have to be in the range [0, 3]. The coordinates are arranged in a quad and a quad can be drawn by 2 triangles as follows:

```html
1         2
 +-------+
 |     / |
 |   /   |
 | /     |
 +-------+
0         3
```

```cpp
unsigned int index_model[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3
};
```

Comment: I'm no longer using quads, I recently updated but ill try anyway. EDIT: no luck yet but thanks.

Comment: @JoeCool The indices have to be 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3. See the answer.